# parfor error for variables or not saving them

Tags: matlab

I want to use parfor matlab code for its fast implementation, but there are two problem. the code that is used, is as follow:

```
for i=1:4
...
    parfor j=1:10
    ...
        para{i,j,:}=cell(1,1,2); %first type of definition
    Alpha{i,j,:}=cell(1,1,2); %first type of definition
    B{i,j,:}=cell(1,1,2); %first type of definition
    para=cell(1,1,2); %second type of definition
    Alpha=cell(1,1,2); %second  type of definition
    B=cell(1,1,2); %second  type of definition
    for k=1:2
        ...
            para{i,j,k}=x1;
        Alpha{i,j,k}=alpha;B{i,j,k}=b;
    end
    ...
    end
mysave(alpha,para,B)
end
```

Now my problems are:

- 1.when I use the first type of definition matlab gives me the error of
  not being able to classify the variables, the reason of my first type
  definition is that I want to save my result at last, for example
  Alpha should be 4*10*2 cell array.
- 2.when I use the second type of definition the error is omitted, but at last only the last cell, I mean the 4th, 10th, cell has the value,
  and other contents are empty. what can be the solution of this
  problem?

I read nearly all post related to parfor matlab, but I cant get my answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it has nothing to do with parfor. If I understand your question correctly, you are defining the variables `Alpha, B, para` inside the for loop. try pre-allocating the size of the cell outside all of the for loops. If this does not solve your problem, show us an example.

Comment: Try reading up on 'for' loops instead. 'parfor' distributes your loop over different cores or workers, but in essence it is nothing different than a 'for' loop.

Comment: @Naveen Thanks for your quick reply, I did your suggestion before, but it did not work and had the same error"not able to classify variables". As I understand, the variables that their size are changed in for loop, in parfor usage, should be define exactly before the related for loop.

Comment: @Fraukje you mean using for loop instead of parfor? if so, my program is correct over using for loops, but the run time is a lot. By using parfor, as I see,(for my second definition type and for 2 cores), the time is half of the main time. my problem is that in the second type definition matlab does not assign values to the vairables and it is correct also. but I don not know how to solve it.

Comment: I have another question also, the last for loop is done randomly(I mean the for that is in the parfor loop). How can it be possible?

Comment: I would suggest trying to run it with a for loop first instead of parfor, possibly with only a j=1:3 to reduce runtime. Could you maybe post a sample example?

Comment: I cant reduce the number of for loop steps, because of high run time and also the number of cores I have, I prefer using the parfor loop. example about what you mean?what part of my question is not clear? please tell me to explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

This was what I suggested. It worked and gave the result cell arrays `Alpha,para,B` with dimensions `4*10*2`. Please look at your code. with `mysave` command you wrote `alpha` instead of `Alpha` which gives you the last value of the loop. If that is a typo, please try the following code. This should work.

```
Alpha=cell(4,10,2); % Number of times the three loops run (4,10,2)
    para=cell(4,10,2);
    B=cell(4,10,2);
    for i=1:4
    %   ...
        parfor j=1:10
    %         ...
            for k=1:2
    %             ...
                para{i,j,k}=x1;
                Alpha{i,j,k}=alpha;
                B{i,j,k}=b;
            end
        end
    end 
    mysave(Alpha,para,B)
```

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake on code here but in my matlab code I wrote it correctly. I did your suggestion but before running I have a warning : The PARFOR loop can not run due to the way the variable "para" used.  And after run the Error: The variable para in a parfor cannot be classified.

Comment: @user2579230 I guess the `parfor` error is due to other part of the code. I have tested the code I have pasted here with constant values assigned to `alpha,x1,b`. It gave the result with out any error or warning. Please look into the `parfor help`.

Comment: I put sth  wrong here also:( In my main code the mysave function is in the parfor loop. please replace the mysave function there, the reason of mistake is this function and its place. As I replace it to the place that you put or the place that I put at first of this page, this error does not appear. Is it possible to use this function in the parfor loop?I need to seve data at each iteration of the parfor loop.

Comment: @user2579230 If you try to save the variables in a loop, the problem is that the old saved variables are replaced by the new ones. Further I have never come across `mysave` function in MATLAB. Is it your custom routine?

Comment: Why do you say that? The for loop steps are not iteration, they are the steps of the final result, so as the for loops propagate the steps are going ahead.